# GoogleUtilities/GULSceneDelegateSwizzler.h file not found

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart

Unable to build Flutter app on iOS/Xcode

[Pubspec file with used dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PbiP.png)

Already tried all the pod install/upgrade, flutter clean, pub install etc solutions.

Error message looks like this:

```
 ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Auth/FIRAuth.m:32:9: fatal error:
    'GoogleUtilities/GULSceneDelegateSwizzler.h' file not found
    #import <GoogleUtilities/GULSceneDelegateSwizzler.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ios/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Firebase/Auth/Source/Auth/FIRAuth.m:32:9: note: did not find header
    'GULSceneDelegateSwizzler.h' in framework 'GoogleUtilities' (loaded from 'build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities')
    1 error generated.
```

Would be very grateful for any input on this issue.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update pods from Terminal:

```
pod update
```

That should resolve your problem.

ps. backup your app before update

Comment: That actually solved it, seems like I used upgrade instead of update. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Move into iOS directory (in your flutter project) and update pod

```
cd ios
pod update
cd..
flutter clean
```